# Converting Const char * to Unsigned long int - strtoul

Tags: c++, type-conversion, unsigned

I am using the following code to convert `Const char *` to `Unsigned long int`, but the output is always `0`. Where am I doing wrong? Please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<string> tok;
    tok.push_back("2");
    const char *n = tok[0].c_str();
    unsigned long int nc;
    char *pEnd;
    nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,1);
    //cout<<n<<endl;
    cout<<nc<<endl; // it must output 2 !?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if anyone wants to convert it to an `unsigned long long`, the function is [`std::stoull`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoull/), while an `unsigned long` is [`std::stoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoul/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,10);
```

You used `base=1` that means only zeroes are allowed.

If you need info about integer bases you can read [this](http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/conv.htm)

Comment: Thanks! for the link. So this base is normally octal/ decimal/ binary/ hexa etc right?

Comment: Yes, also exists some *exotic* bases as in your case base(1), I cannot find word for that.

Comment: What if I want conversion from `Const char * to Unsigned long int *` ? Can you please let me know...

Comment: @user result after conversion is storen into memory and its representation is variable in this case variable is named `nc`. If you want to have pointer you need to use `&nc`

Comment: @user this needs to be changed into:  `unsigned long int nc; nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,10); cout<<&nc<<endl;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38890/discussion-between-user2754070-and-st3)

Answer (score 4):

Use base-10:

```
nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,10);
```

or allow the base to be auto-detected:

```
nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,0);
```

The third argument to `strtoul` is the base to be used and you had it as base-1.

Comment: Thanks!, but what is this `base`? can you explain briefly? I have read it here `strtol` its not clear.

Comment: To use base parameter as zero is not the best idea, for example look at my decimal number: 10101010

Comment: @user2754070: [See here](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28mathematics%29). You should recall it from school and  terms like `decimal`, `binary`, etc.

Comment: Yeah! I've got it from ST3's link http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/conv.htm. : )

Comment: @ST3: And what about `10101010` is significant?

Comment: @ST3: `strtoul` always treats it as decimal unless it starts with a `0` or `0x`.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard library function [strtoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) takes as its third argument the [base/radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) of the number system to be used in interpreting the char array pointed to by the first argument.

> Where am I doing wrong?
>
> nc=strtoul(n,&pEnd,**1**);

You're passing the base as 1, which leads to a [unary numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) i.e. the only number that can be repesented is 0. Hence you'd get only that as the output. If you need decimal system interpretation, pass 10 instead of 1.

Alternatively, passing 0 lets the function auto-detect the system based on the prefix: if it starts with *0* then it is interpreted as octal, if it is *0x* or *0X* it is taken as hexadecimal, if it has other numerals it is assumed as decimal.

**Aside:**

- If you don't need to know the character upto which the conversion was considered then passing a dummy second parameter is not required; you can pass `NULL` instead.
- When you're using a C standard library function in a C++ program, [it's recommended](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-system.html) that you include the C++ version of the header; with the prefix `c`, without the suffix `.h` e.g. in your case, it'd be `#include <cstdlib>`
- `using namespace std;` is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/183120)